# Inline style or class for Forms

Tags: html, css

I am building a asp.net application which has a bunch of forms. 
I don't want to use table for designing Form, as it doesn't seem to be flexible to me. 
Instead, I am using CSS styles. But, each css class for each web control is too much. 
Can I use inline style for each control ?

Comment: I believe CSS classes are the standard universally agreed upon way of styling HTML. Even for forms. But it's ultimately up to you and what works best. Also, this isn't really an asp.net question as it is just about how to structure your CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe use css classes for your website.its take too much time to use your inline css on all pages.and its very time consuming process

Answer (score 1):

You can use inline formatting. However there is no many difference in amount of inline or external styles where placing styles in a CSS file will make it more standard for further edits.